# sending php data to javascript click event

Tags: javascript, php

I have a loop in php that for each item, a link that opens a lightbox is generated.  How can I pass data related to the current iteration (such as the userid) in such a way that I can use it in the lightbox and the form submission?

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $viewUser)
    {
            if ($viewUser)
            {
                echo '<a class="change-email" href="#">Change Email</a>';
            }
    }
}
?>

<script>
$(function(){
    $(".change-email").click(function(){

            $.fancybox({
                'href'              : '#change-email-dialog',
                'width'             : '200px',
                'height'            : 'auto',
                'autoScale'         : true,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'              : 'inline',
                'modal'             : false,
                'afterShow'         : function () {

                }
            });
        });
});   
</script>

<div id="change-email-dialog">
    <form id="change-email-form" class="table" method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('customerservice/changeEmail').'user='.$viewUser->getBusID(); ?>">
        <ul class="table-row">
            <li class="table-cell">New Email</li>
            <li class="table-cell"><input type="text" name="newEmail" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="table-row">
            <li class="table-cell">Notify Contract Entry?</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="notify" /></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="table-row">
            <li><input name="userSearchSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" /></li>
        </ul>

    </form>  
</div>
```

Comment: What I would do is remove the `.click` from the javascript, add a parameter such as `function(id)` and then when echoing the link, add `onclick=\"function(" . $myid . "\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you can remove the `.click` event from the javascript and just leave the function. Then you would call the function on the `onclick` event in HTML, while also passing your variable(s). It would look like this

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $viewUser)
    {
            if ($viewUser)
            {
                echo '<a class="change-email" href="#" onclick="changemail(' . $myid . ');">Change Email</a>';
            }
    }
}
?>

<script>
function changemail(myid){
$.fancybox({
    'href'              : '#change-email-dialog',
    'width'             : '200px',
    'height'            : 'auto',
    'autoScale'         : true,
    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
    'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
    'type'              : 'inline',
    'modal'             : false,
    'afterShow'         : function () {

    }
}
</script>
```

Where `myid` in javascript would contain whatever `$myid` contained in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any data into html

```
echo '<a class="change-email" href="#" data-userid="$viewUser.id">Change Email</a>';
```

and pull it later with js

```
$(this).data('userid')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use data attributes.

Add them to your php ..

```
echo '<a class="change-email" href="#" data-userid=".$userID.">Change Email</a>';
```

.. then you can easily access them in javascript ..

```
this.dataset.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    foreach ($results as $viewUser)
        {
                if ($viewUser)
                {
                    echo '<a data-user="<?=$viewUser->userId?>" class="change-email" href="#">Change Email</a>';
                }
        }
    }
    ?>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".change-email").click(function(){
            var user = $(this).data("user");

            $.fancybox({
                'href'              : '#change-email-dialog',
                'width'             : '200px',
                'height'            : 'auto',
                'autoScale'         : true,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'              : 'inline',
                'modal'             : false,
                'afterShow'         : function () {
                     $("#user_input").val(user);
                }
            });
        });
});   
</script>

<div id="change-email-dialog">
    <form id="change-email-form" class="table" method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('customerservice/changeEmail').'user='.$viewUser->getBusID(); ?>">
        <input id="user_input" type="hidden" name="user" value="" />
        <ul class="table-row">
            <li class="table-cell">New Email</li>
            <li class="table-cell"><input type="text" name="newEmail" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="table-row">
            <li class="table-cell">Notify Contract Entry?</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="notify" /></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="table-row">
            <li><input name="userSearchSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" /></li>
        </ul>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript Query has a chance to return multiple results

change to this

```
$(function(){
    $(".change-email").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $.fancybox({
                'href'              : '#change-email-dialog',
                'width'             : '200px',
                'height'            : 'auto',
                'autoScale'         : true,
                'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                'type'              : 'inline',
                'modal'             : false,
                'afterShow'         : function () {

                }
            });
        });
    });  
});
```